# Record and Display opencv Webcam video

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, wxpython, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to save the the webcam live stream using wx Buttons.

Here is my code

```
import wx
import vlc
import numpy as np
import time
import os
import user
import cv
import datetime

class MainWindow(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent,capture):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

# video
        videoWarper = wx.StaticBox(self,size=(640,480))
        videoBoxSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(videoWarper, wx.VERTICAL)
        videoFrame = wx.Panel(self, -1,size=(640,480))
        videoBoxSizer.Add(videoFrame,0)
        capture = ShowCapture(videoFrame, capture)
        mainSizer.Add(videoBoxSizer,0)

        parent.Centre()
        self.Show()
        self.SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer)

# Panels
# The first panel holds the video and it's all black
        self.videopanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.videopanel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLACK)

# The second panel holds controls
        ctrlpanel = wx.Panel(self, -1 )
        self.timeslider = wx.Slider(ctrlpanel, -1, 0, 0, 1000)
        self.timeslider.SetRange(0, 1000)
        record = wx.Button(ctrlpanel, label="Record")

# Bind controls to events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRecord, record)

# Give a pretty layout to the controls
        ctrlbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

# box contains some buttons
        box.Add(record)

# Merge box to the ctrlsizer
        ctrlbox.Add(box, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=10)
        ctrlpanel.SetSizer(ctrlbox)

# Put everything togheter
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(ctrlpanel, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.BOTTOM | wx.TOP, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetMinSize((350, 300))

# VLC player controls
        self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()

# -------begin capturing and saving video
    def OnRecord(self, evt):
        capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
        fps = 8
        size = (640, 480)

        writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter('video.avi', cv.CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'), fps, size);
        i = 0

        while i < 1000:
             frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

             frame2 = cv.CreateImage(size, 8, 3)
             cv.CvtColor(frame, frame2, cv.CV_cv.CvtColor(frame, frame2, cv.CV_BGR2RGB))

             cv.WriteFrame(writer, frame2)
             # cv.WaitKey(1000/fps)

class ShowCapture(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent, capture, fps=9):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, (0,0), (640,480))

    self.capture = capture
    ret, frame = self.capture.read()

    height, width = frame.shape[:2]

    parent.SetSize((width, height))

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(width, height, frame)

    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.timer.Start(1000./fps)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.NextFrame)

def OnPaint(self, evt):
    dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
    dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0)

def NextFrame(self, event):
    ret, frame = self.capture.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(frame)
        self.Refresh()

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, title='CamGUI')
panel = MainWindow(frame, capture)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I need to display a live stream of raspberry-pi webcam and record that as well. `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` won't record video and `cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)` won't display livestream. so, i used both in the same code but i ended up getting Error.

I got a livestream of webcam but when i press the record button it throws an Error which look like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "home/pi/record.py", line 76 in OnRecord
      cv.CvtColor(frame, frame2, cv.CV_RGB2XYZ) 
cv2.error: scn ==3 || scn ==4
```

Hope for some expert advice :)

Note - I am using Raspberry-pi.

Comment: You are declaring capture 4 times and I'm, not convinced that `capture = ShowCapture(videoFrame, capture)` is a sound idea. Try adding a digit to the names of each capture variable and see if that gives you any mileage.

Comment: I have made some changes in my code.can you please take a look and correct me if iam wrong. @RolfofSaxony

Comment: Can't help, Sorry, I don't have the equipment. Take a look here, http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/ he's using the `picamera` module to do this sort of thing.

Comment: No prob, i will go through this link. Thanks for that :)